# Java: returning a string from a method

Tags: java, string, class, methods, return

I'd like to point out that I'm very new to Java, which is why I may be making stupid mistakes.

I have a class called "Characters", which consists of 4 variables and multiple methods. All variables are private, so from what I've read, I need to use methods to do anything to them.

One of the methods is supposed to return one of the variables in string form, however I keep getting an error from both eclipse and when I run it. "This method must return a result of type "String". The error occurs on the first line of the method:

```
public String displayStats(String option) {
    switch (option) {
    case "charName":
        System.out.println(charName);
        return charName;
    case "charHealth":
        System.out.println(charHealth);
        String charHealth2 = Integer.toString(charHealth);
        return charHealth2;
    case "charMana":
        System.out.println(charMana);
        String charMana2 = Integer.toString(charMana);
        return charMana2;
    case "charStamina":
        System.out.println(charStamina);
        String charStamina2 = Integer.toString(charStamina);
        return charStamina2;
    default:
        System.out.println("Error on default");}
}

}
```

The full class:

```
package basics;

public class Characters {

    private String charName = "";
    private int charHealth = 0;
    private int charMana = 0;
    private int charStamina = 0;

    public void summoner(Characters player) {
        player.charName = "Summoner";
        player.charHealth = 80;
        player.charMana = 150;
        player.charStamina = 50;}

    public void sentinel(Characters player) {   
        player.charName = "Sentinel";
        player.charHealth = 200;
        player.charMana = 50;
        player.charStamina = 100;}

    public void beserker(Characters player) {
        player.charName = "Beserker";
        player.charHealth = 100;
        player.charMana = 0;
        player.charStamina = 200;}

    public void mage(Characters player) {
        player.charName = "Mage";
        player.charHealth = 80;
        player.charMana = 200;
        player.charStamina = 20;}   

    public String displayStats(String option) {
        switch (option) {
        case "charName":
            System.out.println(charName);
            return charName;
        case "charHealth":
            System.out.println(charHealth);
            String charHealth2 = Integer.toString(charHealth);
            return charHealth2;
        case "charMana":
            System.out.println(charMana);
            String charMana2 = Integer.toString(charMana);
            return charMana2;
        case "charStamina":
            System.out.println(charStamina);
            String charStamina2 = Integer.toString(charStamina);
            return charStamina2;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error on default");}
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think will be returned to the caller if it hits that `default` case?

Comment: Normally you would break from each case statement, and have a single return from your method at the end. Multiple returns from a single method is considered bad practice, as it makes the code harder to follow

Comment: I think I may have focused too much on the declaration of the method. Thank you.

Comment: How does this even compile when all paths don't return a value in the method? Maybe you should check you compiler error/warning settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `displayStats` function you don't return a `String` in all paths of your code.
 This is because the `default` doesn't `return` at all.

Maybe you wanted to write:

```
default:
    return "Error on default";
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning anything in the default case of your switch statement, which means that there is a possibility (however small) that the method won't know what to return.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: `charName` is a string, but `charHealth`, `charMana`, and `charStamina` are ints.  Thus, your `displayStats` function isn't always returning a string.

Also, your default option in your switch statement should return a string as well.

It would be better to create an accessor function for each variable:

```
public String getCharName() {
    return charName;
}

public int getCharHealth() {
    return charHealth;
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The method displayStats must always return a String or throw an exception. Since the code implies that the default case is an error, then throw an exception. At this point rather than create a new class of exception, just throw an IllegalArgumentException -- new IllegalArgumentException(option).  When printed out it will state the type of exception and the value of the invalid option.